# Gameboy emulator plays faster than expected

Tags: c++, windows, timing, emulation

I am trying to make a gameboy emulator, but it plays faster than it should.

This is the timing code I'm using in the main loop.

```
if (cpu.T >= CLOCKSPEED / 40) // if more than 1/40th of cycles passed
{
    // Get milliseconds passed
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndCounter);
    unsigned long long counter = EndCounter.QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart;
    MSperFrame = 1000.0f * ((double)counter / (double)PerfCountFrequency);
    LastCounter = EndCounter;

    // if 1/40th of a second hasn't passed, wait until it passes
    if (MSperFrame < 25)
        Sleep(25 - MSperFrame);
    MSperFrame = 0;
    cpu.T -= CLOCKSPEED / 40;
}
```

- `CLOCKSPEED` is the cycles per second of the gameboy cpu (4194304).
- `cpu.T` is cycles passed until now.
- `PerfCountFrequency` is the result of [QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I called before entering the loop.

When I compare it to another emulator (VBA) which plays at the correct speed, my emulator goes faster. What is the problem here?

Comment: I wouldn't use `QueryPerformancCounter()`. I've heard that since modern CPU's dynamically alter their speed for power savings, this isn't necessarily always accurate though I don't have a definite source for that. I generally use std::chrono::steady_clock for profiling now as long as its granularity is sufficiently smaller than the periods you are trying to time.

Comment: Are you counting Gameboy CPU cycles correctly?

Comment: @RyanP As soon as I include <chrono> I get the message "error count exceeds 100. Stopping compilation. (Using Visual Studio). I'll wait for another solution for now.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes. I compared the logs with another open source emulator I found which worked correctly.

Comment: @devil0150 What compiler are you using? <chrono> was introduced in C++11, so older compilers may not have support for it. Alternatively Boost offers a chrono library as well.

Comment: @devil0150 I see you said visual studio, I think you need 2012 or later to get chrono

Comment: @RyanP I'm using Visual Studio 2013. There's a bunch of syntax errors in using statements in cstring, cstdlib and ctime

Comment: Fixed the errors. Same thing happens with steady_clock. (Maybe because of [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753115/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep is the wrong function here.  From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx it mentions that " If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time"

DirectX may have a method (VBLANK??), but you could work out minor issues by working out what the next frame time should be, and if the sleep is too small, saving up Sleeps until it gets above the timer resolution.